# Need example EXTJS4 app with dockedItems

Tags: extjs4

The following app displays a toolbar on top of some HTML:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'app',
    appFolder: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'border',
            items: [
            {
                region: 'north',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Button'
                }]
            },
            {
                region: 'center',
                html: '<img src="resources/images/image.png">'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

but the following does not:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'app',
    appFolder: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            dockedItems: [{
                dock: 'top',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Button'
                }]
            }],
            items: [
            {
                html: '<img src="resources/images/image.png">'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, I can't find much documentation on using dockedItems.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*dockedItem* is a feature of `Ext.panel.AbstractPanel` (and sub-classes). It is not supported in e.g. `Ext.container.Container` or `Ext.container.Viewport`.

Use a panel instead of the viewport (or alternatively, nest a panel inside the viewport) to show your *dockeItems*:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'app',
    appFolder: 'app',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()',
            layout: 'fit',
            dockedItems: [{
                dock: 'top',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Button'
                }]
            }],
            items: [
            {
                html: '<img src="resources/images/image.png">'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Working JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mistaecko/bDNgB/